# How to use an adress instead of long/lat? Swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, mkmapview

So I want a user to fill out a form with their address in it then have that adress data sent to firebase and when I retrieve it from firebase back to my code I would like it to show up as a pin on the MKMapView inside the app for users to look at.

I dont even know how to write this piece of code so if anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you stating you don't know how to read/write data to Firebase or don't know how to implement MKMapView? Please take a moment to read these two documents: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This site is really for help with existing code issues, not really for writing the code for you. Include what you've tried so far and we'll try to help!

Comment: @Jay I know how to use both but how do you use an adress instead of cordinates? And can i use firebase to store the adresses and then retrieve the data to create a map annotation?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from storing the address in Firebase? As in:  *someRef.setValue("1234 Some Road")*? Along with that, if you pre-define (lookup on google etc) the lat/lon then you could save that in the same node so you have both the address as well as the coordinates. The question is really unclear - can you please think through exactly what you are trying to do, include the code you've attempted and let us know where, in your code, you are stuck?

Comment: @IsaiahBjorklund translating addresses into geological coordinates is called geocoding. I am not sure if Firebase has any built in methods for it (don't think so), but you can either use the Google Maps API or MapKit to do it.

Comment: Also see [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) if you need to do something more with saved coordinates in Firebase (query etc)

Comment: @Jay geofire was exactly what i needed thanks!!